# firebase - Use one ref for an object and push onto it's child array

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire

This code works however I'm using two refs to access different areas of the same object.

A routine may have multiple pages.  Is there a way to create new pages and just use one ref to push pages onto $scope.routine.pages that also create a unique id?

[image]

```
angular.module('screenTester.auth.routine', [
    'screenTester.auth.routine.page'    
])

.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('auth.routine', {
            url: '/routine/:routineId',
            controller: 'RoutineCtrl',
            templateUrl: '/dist/auth/routine/routine.html'
        });

}])

.controller('RoutineCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$firebase', function($scope, $stateParams, $firebase) {

    $scope.routineId = $stateParams.routineId;

    // Combine these two and still create pages with a unique id?
    var ref = new Firebase("https://url.firebaseio.com/user" + $scope.auth.user.id + '/routines/' + $scope.routineId);
    var sync = $firebase(ref);

    var ref = new Firebase("https://url.firebaseio.com/user" + $scope.auth.user.id + '/routines/' + $scope.routineId + '/pages');
    var pagesSync = $firebase(ref);

    $scope.createPage = function() {
        // What method would I use here on `$scope.routine`?        
        $scope.routinePages.$add($scope.newPage);
        $scope.routinePages.$save();
        $scope.newPage = {};
        $scope.toggles.showCreatePage = false;
    };

    $scope.init = function() {
      $scope.routine = sync.$asObject();
      $scope.routinePages = pagesSync.$asArray();

      $scope.newPage = {};
      $scope.toggles = {};
    };

    $scope.init();

}]);
```

Disclaimer: Not my final code I'm learning how firebase works to see if it's a good solution.

Comment: Your example looks fine. Unclear what the question is here. Is something broken?

Comment: @Kato I am using two refs and I'd like to use one.  Is that possible with what I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think using multiple references is a problem in any way. The connection to server is only one.

however if you want to reuse the instance you can try doing something like this:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://url.firebaseio.com/user" + $scope.auth.user.id + '/routines/' + $scope.routineId);

var sync = $firebase(ref);

var pagesSync = $firebase(ref.child('pages'));
```

and here is the [documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-creating-references) I refer to.